# Specified extraction folder with Archive::Rar in perl

Tags: perl, directory, extract, archive, rar

i want to extract an .rar Archive in perl to a specified path.
i tryed this:

```
my $archive= 'text.rar';
my $directory = 'photos';
my $rar = Archive::Rar->new( -archive => $archive );
$rar->Extract(-to => $directory);
```

but that didnt worked out, it always extracts it into my root folder...

is there any comand to tell Archive::Rar an other directory?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any such documented option. You can always try to just `chdir $directory` before extracting. It's not quite pretty, but "should" work.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there is an *un*-documented option:

```
my $rar = Archive::Rar->new( -archive => $archive, -initial => $directory);
$rar->Extract();
```

will do just that.